# Does seperate API project need a copy of MVC ViewModels for mapping?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, asp.net-core-webapi

probably an easy one for you. I've just confused myself a little.

Basically I have 2 separate projects under one solution. My MVC and my API. I was wondering about view model mapping and how/where it takes place.

My understanding is that the API will return domain data, map it to a view model and return it to MVC. Does this then mean the API and MVC projects both need identical view model classes ? The API needs to be able to for example, map DomainModelA to ViewModelA and send it to the MVC project.

MVC would then need to accept the ViewModelA object passed in from API. As they are separate projects however, the MVC project doesn't "know" what a ViewModelA is until I create an identical class for the MVC project.

This sounds like a lot of code duplication so I am no doubt misunderstanding something here.

Any help is appreciated. Sorry if its a dumb question, but hey, I'm here to learn :P

I could probably explain it better too if I knew more about the topic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can define another project which contains common classes used in both api and mvc project

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that neither API or MVC could "see" the ViewModel classes as they are in neither of the 2 projects ?

Comment: just example. on api side validations are different, and on mvc web side you used viewmodel has its seperated validation. better to use different model for api and web

Comment: You can reference to the common project (for example name it CommonModel). In terms of validation, you might use the fluentvalidation which can be integrated with asp.net mvc and api.

Comment: How will you request web api from mvc, by sending request? If mvc and web api are separate project and you would avoid exposing all models from web api to view, you should define separate view model for mapping in them even through they may the same class.